# How to split up to seconds in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a weather csv data and it contains the datetime in the format of **'2018-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC'**, but I would like to make it **'2018-01-01 00:00:00'**. I have tried the following

```
weather['dt_iso'] = weather['dt_iso'].apply(lambda x: time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%z%y')))
```

However, it gives the following error.

> ValueError: time data '2018-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC' does not match
>   format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%z%y'

I have searched several questions regarding to this, but could not find. Any help is appreciated.

To be more precise:

**Input**: 2018-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC

**Output**: 2018-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: you have the capital Y in twice

Comment: Yes, but what is the type for showing the UTC for time.strptime?

Comment: %Z https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

Answer (score 1):

You can use both [strptime() and strftime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to get this output

```
import datetime as dt

i = '2018-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC'
i = dt.datetime.strptime(i,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z %Z")
i = dt.datetime.strftime(i,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print(i)
```

this will give you the output that you need.To apply with dataframes,

```
weather['dt_iso'] = weather['dt_iso'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strftime(dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z %Z'),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Thank you !